# Load external url to div but cant change the styles of the loaded page

Tags: javascript, html, css

So, i'm loading an external URL to a div and it's working fine but i can't change the styles of the loaded page.

My code is:

```js
function load_home() {
  var loadDoc = document.getElementById("content").innerHTML = '<object type="text/html" data="myurlwithsomeparameters"></object>';
}
```

```html
<body onload="load_home()">
  <div class="card-body" id="content"></div>
</body>
```

This code is working fine.The page loads inside my index page, but i cant manipulate the styles of the output. This is what i see when i inspect the page.

[image]

And this is the result on my "main" page:
[image]

As you can see it's apllying the <'pre>. How can i override the styles of the loaded page?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use Ajax, and remove the style when you read the result

Comment: _“How can i override the styles of the loaded page?”_ - the way you are currently doing the loading - not at all, an `object` behaves pretty much the same way as an `iframe`, and when you load external content from a different origin into either of those, you have no outside access to the content - Same Origin Policy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the URL is not from same origin, then you need to use a proxy server.

ASSUMING the url is from the the SAME origin as the page, in jQuery you could do

```
$("#content").load("myurlwithsomeparameters",function() {
  $("#content").html($("#content").find("pre").html());
})
```

which removes the pre tag from around the data

If you just want to style the pre tag, you can do

```
$("#content").load("myurlwithsomeparameters",function() {
  $("#content").html($("#content").find("pre").prop("style","").addClass("myOwnPreStyle");
})
```

Comment: And with that, i can apply the styles to the pre tag on my main page, correct?

Comment: I was trying that but i got blocked by CORS policy.

Comment: Right. That is your own fault for not telling us the `data="myurlwithsomeparameters"` is actually `data="https://someoneelsesurlwithsomeparameters"`

Comment: Yeah, my bad. The service is ours, but i'm on my local machine.

Answer (score 0):

First of all if you do not own the file you load. Or it is not under same origin you can't modify it at all. You will get cross origin exception. This is to prevent other people scripts running on sites that they not own.

If it is your file then You have few options.

a) Modify the loaded page from the page it self.

b) Modify its style/html by Javascript. (inline style)

c) Create a css file, and insert it into the iframe with javascript.

There is plenty of resources for all of these methods even here on stackoverflow.